# How to Make two separate object match rotations in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, rotation, pygame

I am making an asteroid remake of sorts, on of the big things in asteroids is the fact that the bullets rotate to match the objects direction. I have managed to make the bullets come out of the ship, nut it stays the same upright rotation. I would Like to make the bullet match rotation with the ship, so it looks like the bullets are coming out of the ship. My code is long unfortunately, but I do not know what to take out to make it more compact. I just tried to add comments and hope I guess.  Any help is greatly appreciated. The vast majority of the actions happens in the 'MOUSEBUTTONDOWN" code. I have a 'rotate" function for the ship already, I'm thinking maybe we have to just use that, but I am unable to implement it.

The Image for The Ship

[image]

Image for the bullet I Want to rotate

[image]

```
import pygame as game
import pygame.math as math
import random as r

'''
Here I defined things

'''
game.init()


game.display.set_caption("Asteroids")
screen = game.display.set_mode([800,600])
gameon=True
bgcolor = game.color.Color("#FFFFFF")
ship = game.image.load("ship.png")
ship = game.transform.scale(ship, (50, 50))
rect = ship.get_rect()
rect.x=400
rect.y=400
shipdir = 0
newship = ship

auto = False

arrow = game.image.load("bullet.png")
shiphitbox = ship.get_rect()
shiphitbox.x = 100
shiphitbox.y = 100

arrows=[]




#code to rotate the ship
def rotateship(shipdir):
    newship = game.transform.rotate(ship, shipdir)
    newrect = rect.copy()
    newrect.center  = newship.get_rect().center
    return newship.subsurface(newrect).copy()


def getmove():
    #returns x-y movement based on directrion facing
    global shipdir
    d=shipdir
    if d >= 349 or d < 11:

        return [0, -2]
    elif d >=11 and d < 34:
        return [-1,-2]
    elif d >=34 and d < 56:
        return [-2,-2] #
    elif d >=56 and d < 79:
        return [-2,-1]
    elif d >=79 and d < 102:
        return [-2,0]
    elif d >=102 and d < 125:
        return [-2,1]
    elif d >=125 and d < 147:
        return [-2,2] #
    elif d >=147 and d < 170:
        return [-1,2]
    elif d >=170 and d < 191:
        return [0,2]
    elif d >=191 and d < 214:
        return [1,2]
    elif d >=214 and d < 237:
        return [2,2] #
    elif d >=237 and d < 260:
        return [2,1]
    elif d >=260 and d < 282:
        return [2,0]
    elif d >=282 and d < 305:
        return [2,-1]
    elif d >=305 and d < 328:
        return [2,-2] #
    elif d >=328 and d < 349:
        return [1,-2]



##main loop of the game
while gameon:
    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    screen.blit(newship,(rect.x,rect.y))


    key = game.key.get_pressed()
    event=game.event.poll()
    #controls

    if key[game.K_a]:
        if shipdir==0: shipdir=360
        shipdir -= 1
        newship = rotateship(shipdir)

    if key[game.K_d]:
        if shipdir==360: shipdir=0
        shipdir += 1
        newship = rotateship(shipdir)



    if auto==True or key[game.K_SPACE] or key[game.K_w] :
        move = getmove()
        rect.x +=  move[0]
        rect.y +=  move[1]

    game.time.delay(5)

    #shooting
    if event.type==game.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        '''
        This is where the shooting happens
        '''
        arrowbox = arrow.get_rect()
        arrowbox.x = rect.x;
        arrowbox.y = rect.y;
        move = getmove()
        data = [arrowbox, move[0], move[1]]
        arrows.append(data)


    if event.type==game.QUIT:
        gameon=False;

    #spawning projectiles 
    for bullet in arrows:
        bullet[0].x += bullet[1]
        bullet[0].y += bullet[2]

        if bullet[0].x > 700 or bullet[0].x<0:
            arrows.remove(bullet)



    for bullet in arrows:
        screen.blit(arrow,(bullet[0].x,bullet[0].y))




    game.display.flip() #redraws / refreshes screen



##comes here when game is over
while True:
    screen.fill(bgcolor)
    game.display.flip()
    event=game.event.poll()
    if event.type == game.QUIT:
        break

game.quit()
```

Comment: you are already keeping track of ship dir, just use 'game.transform.rotate' on your bullet as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would Like to make the bullet match rotation with the ship, so it looks like the bullets are coming out of the ship.

You have to know the angle of rotation for each separate bullet. Add the  angle of rotation to the bullet data:

```py
data = (arrowbox, move[0], move[1], shipdir)
arrows.append(data)
```

Create rotated bullets by [`pygame.transform.rotate`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.rotate) and [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) it:

```py
for bullet in arrows:
    rotBullet = pygame.transform.rotate(arrow, bullet[3])
    screen.blit(rotBullet, (bullet[0].x, bullet[0].y))
```